# Maximum file upload quantity is too low

Tags: php

I have a successful uploading script, but it won't allow more than 20 jpeg files. I've set the size limit to a max and i've updated everything in the php.ini and php.ini.temp files to limit everything to 200M (i'm assuming that's 200mb). My size limit in my php document is 209715200, which again i'm assuming is in bytes. I've also tried to add an extra input to upload files, and it again will only upload 20 total. in total, i'm able to upload approx 26.6MB.... Can anyone tell me how I can increase this number?

Comment: If you've updated everything in php.ini, it should be ok. Did you reboot your server ?

Comment: i rebooted, tried to upload 43 files, and it says it was successful. Problem is it only uploaded 20 again....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

raise max_file_uploads in php.ini
http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads

Comment: Dont forget to restart the server.